# QR scanner for making trade fair shopping lists

Tags: windows, android, iphone-app, microsoft-excel, qr-code

Is anyone aware of an **android/iPhone** app that would allow customers to go **scan** a **barcode/QR** code on an item and create an **order list**, that could be **exported** for our manufacturing orders?

**Bullet Points of what is needed.**

- Barcode or QR scanner
- User is able to create an item list from items scanned at a trade show
- List can be exported and sorted
- Andoird preferred
- No next connection prefered

**Use case.**

The scenario is as follows. We go to a trade fair once a year to showcase our new products and take orders for the whole financial year coming. However, we are wasting masses of time dealing with the *manual input* of the orders. It's manually typed into the database for weeks after the trade, and not sortable any time before that.

The perfect piece of software would allow our customers to walk around our exhibition, scanning the code for the items they want, adding a quantity, colour and address they would like it sent to.

On the desktop end; we would need it to be sortable by type and customer, colour or material. Exported directly into an **XLS** or **CSV** or whatever else that would be useable.

The current method is to take the *lists* from all customers on the day. Give them to office workers, who then add them manually create **XLS** sheets, and add the notes and items to our *internal database*.

Once that is done, we can see if we have enough of one type to give a full manufacturing order or have to cancel or negotiate with the customer for less or more to create an order.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not tried it in this context, but my list of [Barcode Scanners & Generators](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_barcode_scanner) holds several that can be used for "serial scanning", with the results exported to lists. Closest candidate for your purpose probably is [LoMag Barcode Scanner to Excel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.longint.lomag.scanner); [Universal Barcode & QR Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pd.apps.universel.barcode.scanner.free) also supports bulk scan, but contains nasty trackers (e.g. CallDorado).

Comment: This goes some way to solving the problem. I can see that Barcode to excel can do a lot. I just have to convince my company to use it. Thank you :)

Comment: So shall I make the comment an answer (with some more details) you [can](/help/someone-answers) [accept](/help/accepted-answer) (and point those to be convinced to to read)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some [Barcode Scanners & Generators](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_barcode_scanner)¹ have a feature for "bulk scanning" (a la "peep, peep, peep …" and simply storing what they found), and later let you export the list in some format – either sharing it via e.g. Mail, or exporting it as CSV/Excel.

One such candidate is **[LoMag Barcode Scanner to Excel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.longint.lomag.scanner),** which describes itself as a "completely free barcode scanner enabling you to save data to Microsoft Excel". I have not tested it myself, but it is well rated (4.3 stars at 500+ votes), seems up-to-date (last release about 2 month ago as of this writing), and fitting your needs:

- **Barcode or QR scanner:** Yes.
- **User is able to create an item list from items scanned at a trade show:** Yes. That's what's called "bulk scanning". Quoting from the app's description:
  *You can change your phone into a data collector without any limitations to the amount of collected codes, completely free of charge.*
- **List can be exported and sorted:** Yes. As the name says already, the list can be exported into Excel format. Excel (or any other calc software like LibreOffice Calc) can then be used for sorting.
- **Andoird preferred:** Yes, this is an Android app :)
- **No next connection prefered:** Not sure what you mean – but I guess it can work offline, if it's that.

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshots of LoMag (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.longint.lomag.scanner); click images for larger variants)</sup>

For alternative candidates, please refer to my app listing initially linked. Note however that some other candidates include nasty tracking and advertising modules. My listing points that out where known and offensive; make sure to check with the "linked monitoring icons" to make sure what might be not acceptable.

---

¹ <sub>Disclosure: Link goes to my Android site</sub>

Comment: PS: Just found this [Tutorial](http://www.longint.com/Program_magazynowy.aspx?item=ScannerAndroid) for additional details.